# Commas not displaying in implode

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to separate some taxonomy terms with a comma, but I can't see to get the commas to show correctly.

Here's what I got:

```
<?php
  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'type');
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    $typeName = array();
    $typeName[] = $term->name;
    ?>
    <small><?php echo implode(', ', $typeName); ?></small>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

They seem to echo out just fine. Just can't get the commas to show.

Comment: Put the `implode` after the `endforeach`

Comment: Hmmm, if I do that then it only lists out one of the term names and not all term name that are checked for that custom post type.

Comment: You are resetting the array at every iteration as well. Move that variable definition to before the `foreach`

Comment: This is very basic php which belongs on [so] :-)

Comment: try to put  `$typeName = array();` before `foreach loop` and use '<?php echo implode(',', $typeName); ?>' after `endforeach;`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are defining the `$typeName` variable as an empty array at the stat of each iteration of the loop, effectively erasing it, then filling that empty array with a single term name, which you `implode`. You don't see any commas because you are `implode`ing a one term array. Move the definition to before the Loop and the `implode` to after it.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'category');
$typeName = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  $typeName[] = $term->name;
} ?>
<small><?php echo implode(', ', $typeName); ?></small><?php
```

That said, there are more Wordpress-ie ways to do this. WordPress provides a function called `wp_list_pluck()` that will shorten your labor:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'category');
$typeName = wp_list_pluck($terms,'name'); ?>
<small><?php echo implode(', ',$typeName) ;?></small><?php
```

`get_the_term_list()` may also work for you, though you get hyperlinks and not bare term names:

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'category', $before = '', $sep = ', ', $after = '' ); ?>
<small><?php echo $terms; ?></small><?php
```